# ACF field doesn't show on my WooCommerce membership fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, membership

I'm recently working on WordPress. I faced a problem regarding ACF. ACF field was not shown on my WooCommerce membership fields

I set post type equal to membership plan here:

[image]

This `post_type` is not available in ACF `post_type` options and no custom fields are there in membership plan:

[image]

I expect only one thing, that how this above custom field (ACF) can be shown in membership plan editor.

Comment: Please add screenshot of Membership Plan edit screen, with Screen Options drawer open: https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/screen-options/.

Comment: Funnily enough, I've just stumbled into this very issue. When selecting the post type "wc_membership_plan" as an option in the location rule, it never outputs on the edit page. After a frustrating hour, I've just recalled a similar issue with their Teams for WC Memberships plugin. They restrict which meta boxes display on their edit pages. There's a filter for this is seems - wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids. This link (albeit for Pods, not ACF) could help: https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/4675

Comment: An alternative could also be to hook into the tabs and add regular custom fields, as per the tutorial here: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/memberships-plan-settings-tabs.html    I do share the frustration at that approach though, as all I want to do is use ACF's Post Object field to pick a related post. It's a much nicer interface than typing in a post id!

Comment: Aha! I have this working - will write an answer for you now.

Comment: Hey @ArunSaini - have you tried the solution posted? If so, can you please accept the answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself today and have figured it out. It's because the WooCommerce Memberships plugin restricts the meta boxes that can be displayed on the edit pages.

I had the same issue in their sister plugin, Teams for WooCommerce Memberships.

In both plugins, they provide a filter to add your meta box to the white list. For WooCommerce Memberships it's:

`wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids`

If you were wanting to allow a custom meta box called `my_meta_box`, you would do this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids', 'my_custom_wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids' );

function my_custom_wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids( $ids ) {

   $ids[] = 'my_meta_box';

   return $ids;

}
```

But here, rather than a meta box we've created from scratch, we're looking to add a meta box created by Advanced Custom Fields. How do we find the meta box ID for that?

If you go to the edit Field Group page for your desired field group, we can find it.

1. Open Screen Options.
2. Tick `slug`.
3. In the slug panel, grab the group name. For example, mine is `group_649caa05c7671`.
4. Prepend this value with 'acf-' and you have your meta box ID! Mine would be `acf-group_649caa05c7671`.

So a complete filter function would be:

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids', 'my_acf_wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids' );

function my_acf_wc_memberships_allowed_meta_box_ids( $ids ) {

   $ids[] = 'acf-group_649caa05c7671';

   return $ids;

}
```

I tested saving and retrieving a field on a membership plan and it worked a treat.

### Bonus content!

#### Adding fields via plan details tabs

For those of you who want to add regular custom fields without ACF, you can add extra tabs to the Membership Plan settings panel using the `wc_membership_plan_data_tabs` filter. Misha Rudrastyh has a [great tutorial on this](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/memberships-plan-settings-tabs.html).

#### Adding to Teams for WooCommerce Memberships

As mentioned above, I initially joined the dots on this question because I'd seen similar on the sister plugin. For those of you who need to add meta boxes on Team edit pages, the filter is very similar:

`wc_memberships_for_teams_allowed_meta_box_ids`

### Thanks to:

Credit for finding an ACF meta box goes to [Advanced Ads](https://wpadvancedads.com/manual/allow-custom-meta-boxes-on-ad-edit-screen/). Thanks guys!